# What is Retracing in context of this Question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics

My textbook Question is

> Two Mirrors are inclined at an acute angle theta.Light ray is incident parallel to one of the mirrors. Light will start retracing its path after third reflection if angle theta is-
>
> 1. 45 degree
> 2. 30 degree
> 3. 60 degree
> 4. all three

Does retracing after 3rd reflection means 3 images will form? But how could that be true for an acute angle? (Because if theta is 90 degree then 3 images are formed). If not (I hope no) than what does it mean here?

Comment: Hi Mohit and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I would guess *retracing* means the light ray reflects away from the two mirrors along the same path that it travelled towards the two mirrors. That is, the incoming and outgoing rays coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about the question, I'm not going to give you the answer.
I'll just give you some clues.

Clues:
1. Acute angle is any angle less than 90 Degree ignoring Negative value.  ( 0 < Theta < 90 )
2. Retracing means the "Output Light" goes back to the point of  "Input Light" and is parallel to each other.

---

Characteristics of the Image Below:
1. Input Light is Parallel to "Mirror 2".
2. Input Light Hits "Mirror 1", "Mirror 2", "Mirror 1" in total of 3 Reflections.
3. Output Light is the result of 3rd Reflection.
4. Output Light is not yet going back to the point of Input Light nor Parallel to it.

[image: 3 Reflections of Light]

---

Your Task Now:
1. Modify the angle "Theta" until the Output Light goes back to the point of Input Light and is parallel to the Input Light.

Goodluck... : )